# How do I clear VLC's stored passwords?

Tags: passwords, vlc-media-player

When I start VLC using `vlc --ignore-config` or `vlc --reset-config` (either of which should, I think, give me a fresh new VLC), when I provide a valid user but an incorrect password for an RTSP stream, it plays fine because I've used the correct password previously.

If I use an incorrect username (or perhaps one where I've never put the password in correctly before), it just keeps asking for the password.

Does anyone know where VLC stores credentials? (I don't think it can be in `~/.config/vlc`, where preferences are stored, because I've tried deleting that directory and it still remembers the password.) Or some sneaky way to tell VLC to clear them or not to use them this time, that would work for me too!

I'm using VLC 3.0.9.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 (well, Mint 20.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon my VLC passwords just now whilst looking into something else.

In Mint (I'm still on v20.2), I chose "Passwords and Keys" from the start menu, which, I discovered, is the same as running `seahorse` from the command line.

The `man` page for `seahorse` says:

> Seahorse is a graphical interface for managing and using encryption keys, passwords and certificates. Currently it supports PGP keys (using GPG/GPGME) and SSH keys. Its goal is to provide an easy to use Key Management Tool, along with an easy to use interface for encryption operations.

When run, it seems to start on the "GnuPG keys" area for some reason; I needed to press the back button (a left arrow) to see the full list of sections.  Then I went into one of two "Login" sections listed beneath "Passwords".  (Could be just me, but I had one that's unlocked and one that's locked; I went into the unlocked one.)

The list that resulted included various entries prefixed "LibVLC password for...".  The search at the top enabled me to filter down to ones I was interested in (even just entering "VLC" in the search helped).  Then I could view and/or delete entries.